# Test Driven Development in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, tdd

I'm trying to figure out how to apply Test Driven Development (TDD) in machine learning tasks. All I know is that, in Machine Learning you need to:

1. Train using a set of training (and validation if a validation set is chosen to be provided) features and their corresponding labels (or none if it's unsupervised learning), and training parameters to produce models.
2. Test the models using a set of test features to know how well they perform with unseen data.
3. Predict using the models.

Are these the only things I should write tests for? How do I go about applying TDD in Machine Learning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Benefits of TDD in machine learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437406/benefits-of-tdd-in-machine-learning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that TDD is more connected to the code development than to using ML algorithms, which is more engineering work. It would be hard to apply TDD there. You should focus on methodology more.

However, much of ML work is really data preparation, cleaning, feature processing and development etc. Often, such tasks are data-related. There is a lot of space for TDD there.